# How to setup button click for Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have multiple button at my webpage, below is example in cshtml:

**home.cshtml**

```
<Button runat="server" id="Search_Click" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" >try</Button>
```

and below is **Home.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Web;
namespace WebApplication2.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        { }
        public IActionResult btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { return Redirect("/Login");}
    }
}
```

But the button here is not function at all, anyone have ideas on this?

Comment: Seems you are trying to mix concepts between webforms and aspnet-mvc. MVC doesn't have the concept of `runat="server"`. Unless its a link or a form submit, you'll need to use javascript to interact with buttons.

Comment: Are you trying to mix Razor Pages and Web Forms framework all together?

Answer (score 3):

**Razor Pages is not just Web Forms as both technologies are very different.** It is true that, from a file organization point of view, you can definitely see some similarities. After all, both in Razor Pages and Web Forms we have the focus on pages with some code behind them. However, the way that they go about implementing actual websites is completely different.

Just to be clear, I don’t subscribe to the idea that Web Forms is a bad technology or that it was badly designed. For its time, Web Forms was a huge step forward in terms of rapid application development. Also, its model tried to abstract away all the nuance of HTTP and offer a development experience that was very similar to what was seen before in Windows Forms.

Anyway, Razor Pages is very different from ASP.NET Web Forms. First of all, in Razor Pages, there’s no abstraction of HTTP whatsoever. Actually, what you see in those Page Model files is not an HTML page’s “Code Behind“, what you see are HTTP-Verb-specific Action Methods of sorts that the framework calls for handling requests. You’re going to see methods like `OnGet` and `OnPost`, instead of `Button_OnClick` or `DropDownList1_OnSelect`. Much like MVC, you also have access to the complete Request, Response and HttpContext objects that help out in processing requests. Also, the main pain points in WebFroms: Postbacks and the ViewState, are nowhere to be found. Instead, everything is stateless and you’re 100% in control of the messaging that’s happening between server and client. Refer to [here](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2018/11/20/whats-the-deal-with-asp-net-core-razor-pages) for more details .

I suggest you could take some time to learn [the official tutorial on Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).